# Lax-Milgram theorem proof in Brezis book.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, solution-verification

I am reading Brezis book "FA, Sobolev Sp. and PDEs" and I am working through the proof of **Stampacchia theorem (5.6 page 138 2010 edition)** and I am particulary interested in **Lax-Milgram theorem (which is given as a Corollary 5.8)**.

Lax-Milgram theorem is proven as a corollary of Stampacchia theorem invoking **corollary 5.4**, which states

> Suppose $W$ is a closed linear subspace of $H.$ For $x\in H,$ $y=P_Kx$
>   is characterized by the property that for all $\omega \in W$ $$ y\in W
> \ \text{and} \ \langle x-y, \omega \rangle =0.$$

How does one prove Lax Milgram from this?

**My explanation**

> What I would say is that taking $H=K$ we argue as in Stampacchia theorem (keeping in mind that for $H$ the above argument applies with $H=W$)
>   to obtain the unique $u \in H$ such that for all $v \in H$
>   $$a(u,v-u+u)=\ell (v-u+u),$$ where we have an equality ($= 0$) instead of an inequality ($\leq 0$) precisely because we have so in the corollary 5.4, and the same goes about the $+u$ factor. And then when $a$ is symmetric the Stampacchia's argument completely carries over without any change so that the minimizing function is the same but we minimize it over $H$ instead of $K.$
>
> Is it correct? I would like to make it more precise, any suggestions?

**Note** I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3502330/lax-milgram-as-a-corollary-of-stampacchia-theorem-brezis-book) recent question which asks the same thing but has received answers that are not very to the point, since they just give standard proofs of Lax-Milgram without any reference to Stampacchia's theorem, which is not what the other (and my own) question was about at all. So I ask hoping to receive a more on-topic answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stampacchia theorem yields the existence of $u$ such that
$$
a(u,v-u) \ge l(v-u) \quad\forall v\in H.
$$
Take $w\in H$. Then we can set $v = \pm w+u$ to obtain the equality
$$
a(u,w) = l(w) \quad \forall w\in H.
$$

If $a$ is symmetric then
$$
(u,v) \mapsto a(u,v)
$$
is an inner product that induces a norm that is equivalent to the norm on $V$.
And the energy minimization problem is a quadratic minimization problem.

To prove the claim about the energy minimization, the book says 'argue as in Corollary 5.4' (and not apply Corollary 5.4). Corollary 5.4 makes a connection between a projection problem (which is the minimization of a quadratic function like our energy minimization) and an inequality (which in our case is the desired equation). So to prove the equation you have to repeat the arguments in the proof of Corollary and apply them to the new situation.
A more direct proof can be found in   [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3502833/136544) to the other question.

Comment: Yes, but the minimization argument is the same as in the Stampacchia theorem. So my question is: is there anything more to say other than "it's the same argument"?

Comment: I missed that the formulation of the Stampacchia theorem also includes a statement about energy minimization.

Comment: Also, with applying corollary 5.4 I meant that $H$ is a linear subspace, so one can take $W=H$ and use corollary 5.4 to rewrite the property that $u$ need satisfy as an equality instead of an inequality. Then the argument in Stampacchia's carries over just as is, or is it more difficult than this?

Comment: I am not interested in a direct proof. I am interested in understanding the approach of Brezis' through Stampacchia's theorem